# Why does this simple Node, Sequelize Promise code hang?

Tags: node.js, promise, sequelize.js

I'm trying to do a simple command line database transformation with node.js and sequelize. I've simplified my errant code down to the following, but it never returns:

```
// Set up database connection and models
var models  = require('../models_sequelize');

models.User.findOne()
  .then(a => {
    console.log(a.name);
  });
```

I get a name printed, but then the script hangs. What is wrong? How do I debug this to see what's stuck? I get the impression that there's an orphan promise that's not being fulfilled, but I don't understand where or why. I must be missing something obvious.

If I run the same interactively from the node console, it returns fine.

Comment: Shouldn't there be something like a `close()` method to kill the database connection, after you are finished?

Comment: even if he put close, its not going to change anything. Can you please share more code block detail here? also try to put everything in try catch block to identify problem

Comment: I've simplified the code down to very little, including removing the catch that didn't add to the issue. Presumably any exception will be spat out on the console anyway? Close seemed to fix it, so presumably that's what it was blocking on.

Answer (score 2):

Sirko's comment re: close() gave me something to go on. I can stop the hanging with the following code:

```
var models  = require('../models_sequelize');

models.User.findOne()
  .then(a => {
    console.log(a.name);
    models.sequelize.close();
  })
```

Alternatively, this seems to work too as I guess it's doing exactly the same thing:
    var models  = require('../models_sequelize');

```
models.User.findOne()
  .then(a => {
    console.log(a.name);
  })
  .finally(() => {
    models.sequelize.close();
  });
```

I also found something about connection pooling timeouts, but I don't think that affects my simple use case. I imagine it'll come into play in more complicated examples.

Would still like to find a good reference as to why this is necessary rather than just my guess.

Comment: Another option for you is that you can call `process.exit()`.  That will implicitly close the database connection as well.

Comment: While this is the correct answer, it remains an indication of poor quality on sequelize's part that it leaves hanging awaits in this form.